# SOS, $scope not working on algular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am making a http.get that is giving me this answer below, that i am getting from a localhost json:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 52562,
    "title": "Event name",
    "startDate":"20-03-20",
    "endDate": "20-03-20",
    "description": "Lorem ipsun doloren he jlhdkh skjrlkuslinf  sidhkjh this is a test",
    "imageUrl": [
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg",
    ],
    "donateTypes": [{
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "Fraldas",
      "min": 2,
      "total": 12
    }, {
       "_id": 1,
      "name": "Fraldas",
      "min": 2,
      "total": 12
    }, {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "Fraldas",
      "min": 2,
      "total": 12
    }]
  }
];
```

The thing is, in my html the scope is not rendering, i really don't know why and i have already tried everything! i dont know what to do! anybody can help? 
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="saoVicentinoApp">

  <head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.2.14" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="EventController.js"></script>
    <script src="github.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <h1>Sao Vicente</h1>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

github.js
(function(){

```
  var github = function($http){
     var getUser = function(){
       return $http.get("http://localhost/course1/finalAndCorrect/json")
       .then(function(response){ 
         return response.data; 
       });

     };
    return{ //what i return will represent the public api
      getUser: getUser
    };
  };

  var module = angular.module("saoVicentinoApp"); 
  module.factory("github", github);
}());
```

app.js:

```
(function(){
  var app = angular.module("saoVicentinoApp", ["ngRoute"]);

  app.config(function($routeProvider){ //do this configuration when bringing this module to life
    $routeProvider
      .when("/", {
        templateUrl:"user.html",
        controller:"EventController"
      })
      .otherwise({redirectTo:"/"});
  });
}());
```

EventController.js:

```
(function(){
angular.module('saoVicentinoApp')
.controller('EventController', ['$scope', 'github', function($scope, github){
$scope.test = 4;
var onUserComplete = function(data){

  $scope.event = data;
  console.log($scope.event);
};

var onError = function(reason){
  $scope.error = "Could not fetch the data.";
};


github.getUser()
.then(onUserComplete, onError);

}]);
}());
```

user.html

```
    <!--  event Container  -->
    <div class="list-group">
      <!--  event Container  -->
      <div class="list-group-item">
        <h3>{{event.title}}
          <em class="pull-right">{{event.startDate}} - {{event.endDate}}</em>
        </h3>

        <!-- Image Gallery  -->
        <div ng-show="event.imageUrl.length">
        <!-- Fail 1 Message -->
          <div ng-show="event.imageUrl">
            <img class="img img-circle img-thumbnail center-block" ng-src="{{event.imageUrl[0]}}" />
           <!-- <ul class="clearfix">
              <li class="small-image pull-left thumbnail" ng-repeat="image in event.imageUrl"> <img ng-src="{{image}}" /> </li>
            </ul>-->
          </div>
        </div>

        <section>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li><a href ng-click="tab = 1">Description</a></li>
            <li><a href ng-click="tab = 2">Como posso contribuir?</a></li>
            <li><a href ng-click="tab = 3">Calendario</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="panel" ng-show="tab === 1">
            <h4>Description</h4>
            <blockquote>{{event.description}}</blockquote>
          </div>
          <div class="panel" ng-show="tab === 2">
            <h4>Como posso contribuir?</h4>
            <div ng-repeat="donations in event.donateTypes">
              <div>{{donations.name}}</div>
              <div>{{donations.min}}</div>
              <div>{{donations.total}}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel" ng-show="tab === 3">
            <h4>Calendario</h4>
            <blockquote>None yet</blockquote>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the promise from the factory. Since you are using promise`(.then)` from then controller no need to use it from the factory. Just return the http request

github.js

```
(function(){

  var github = function($http){
     var getUser = function(){
       return $http.get("http://localhost/course1/finalAndCorrect/json")
     };
    return{ //what i return will represent the public api
      getUser: getUser
    };
  };

  var module = angular.module("saoVicentinoApp"); 
  module.factory("github", github);
}());
```

You json is also invalid

```
[  
   {  
      "_id":52562,
      "title":"Event name",
      "startDate":"20-03-20",
      "endDate":"20-03-20",
      "description":"Lorem ipsun doloren he jlhdkh skjrlkuslinf  sidhkjh this is a test",
      "imageUrl":[  
         "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg"
      ],
      "donateTypes":[  
         {  
            "_id":1,
            "name":"Fraldas",
            "min":2,
            "total":12
         },
         {  
            "_id":1,
            "name":"Fraldas",
            "min":2,
            "total":12
         },
         {  
            "_id":1,
            "name":"Fraldas",
            "min":2,
            "total":12
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

And data in http response comes under data property. So change this

```
var onUserComplete = function(data){

  $scope.event = data.data[0];
  console.log($scope.event);
};
```

Comment: why invalid the json?

Comment: there is a unnecessary comma in it. use online tool to check it out

Comment: @Catarina Nogueira check the demo https://plnkr.co/edit/HrlGDIf3cJxRhE6BmbfU?p=preview

Comment: i but your json but still i got nothing :/

Comment: @Catarina Nogueira sorry my mistake data in http req data comes under data property so use this `$scope.event = data.data[0];` check the demo again

Comment: many thanks, omg!! But, what should i do if i want to render in my html all objects in this json(i want to add more objects at it)? how should i do the ng-repeat?

Comment: then remove the position of data array `$scope.event = data.data` like this. Now `$scope.even` is an array.now use `ng-repeat` to loop the data in html

Comment: like <div ng-repeat="what should i put here"> </div> i don't know this $scope.even :/

Comment: check the demo again

Comment: `<div ng-repeat="ev in event">`  Now the `{{event.description}}` should change to `{{ev.description}}`. need apply this to all things like this

Comment: @Catarina Nogueira no problem. make sure to upvote and mark as answer :D